# Displaying image retrieved from memory, as a button background

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a button on my view. I want to display an image as the background on it. The image is previously stored on the memory by the same application.

`NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *uniquePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:"Image.jpg"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: uniquePath];

[btnImage setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Every-time I execute the code, the application crashes after the end of the method that contains the above code. I tried debugging, and found that every step executes perfectly, but the application crashes at the end. I guess that problem is with setting the image as the button background. Can anyone help me out of this??

Thanks in advance

P.S i am writing the above code in viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Interface Builder you can simply set the Image from one of the properties; this is assuming the image were added to your bundle.

Otherwise if the image is loaded at run-time and/or you're doing everything in code, which I
'm guessing you are.. I think the problem is with the "NSString *uniquePath ..." line. Have you run the code in the debugger?  Is the variable uniquePath nil?

UPDATE: browsing this question again, I saw the problem.

You're not retaining a copy of your image instance variable - do this before returning from -viewDidLoad.  Remember to release it in -viewDidUnload